# How to display the output of the product variant metafields in Shopify product page?

Tags: shopify, variant

I am using metafields editor to display some additional information in the Shopify store. I need help in displaying the output of the below product variant metafields in Shopify product page. What code do I need to add into the product.liquid file? Do I also need to have a JavaScript snippet?

**Product description metafield for product variants:**

namespace: variantdescription
key: Product Description
value: This is product description for variant A
value_type: string

**Product delivery metafield for product variants:**

namespace: variantdelivery
key: Delivery Time
value: This is delivery time for variant A
value_type: string

Answer (score 1):

You can get the metafield value with this code:

```
product.metafields.NAMESPACE.KEY
```

The code that you have to use for product description will be something like this:

```
{%- if product.metafields.variantdescription.product_description != blank -%}

    {{ product.metafields.variantdescription.product_description }}

{%- endif -%}
```

It will be like this for the Delivery time:

```
{%- if product.metafields.variantdelivery.delivery_time != blank -%}

    {{ product.metafields.variantdelivery.delivery_time }}

{%- endif -%}
```

Here is the information about how to use metafields in liquid.
https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects/metafield

JavaScript is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Get Description of current variant:

```
{% assign description = current_variant.metafields.variantdescription%}
{% assign key =  current_variant.sku  %}
{% assign description = description[key] %}
```

Likewise for product delivery